# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Headers in wampserver 3

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, cors, wampserver

i am trying to access to XMLHttpRequest with my ionic app on localhost:8100/ to laravel API host on wampserver 3.1.7 32 bit.

I already did in wamp

1 : httpd.conf : I changed "#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so" to "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so".

2 : httpd.conf : I add :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

3 in httpd-vhosts.conf : I add "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" in

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias localhost
 DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   AllowOverride All
   Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I still get this error when I tried to make an ajax request between ionic to laravel :

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/cn/public_html/api/auth/login' from origin 
 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not 
 allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Plou/5809547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this package :

[laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

i hope can help you